# Adding array into mysql varchat row with comma after creating the array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a huge table with some items. I want to retrive specific items from that table according with the players level of gaming . After the code extracts all the specific items i want to add them into an array ( in this case "`$cart`") . I want to update a mysql row into a varchar field the array separated by a comma ",";

I tried different methods of adding them into the database but something isn't working.

Heres my code :

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from iteme where tip != 'Minereu' AND tip != 'Reteta' AND   tip != 'Cooking' AND tip != 'Altele' AND tip != 'Potiuni' AND tip != 'Fragment' AND tip != 'Tools' AND tip != 'Medicina' ");

$numaratoare = 0;
$cart = array();
$nivel_player = mysql_query("select * from membri where id !=0 ");

while($informatie_player = mysql_fetch_array($nivel_player))
{
    $nivel_actual_player = lvl($informatie_player['experienta']);
    $shop_arme_plus_5 = $nivel_actual_player + 5 ;
    if ($nivel_actual_player - 5 == 0 )
        $shop_arme_minus_5 = $nivel_actual_player - 5 ;
    else
        $shop_arme_minus_5 = 0 ;


    $shop_arme = mysql_query("select * from iteme where tip = 'Arme' AND level_minim < ".$shop_arme_plus_5." AND level_minim > ".$shop_arme_minus_5." AND vandabil = 1 ");

    while($informatie = mysql_fetch_array($shop_arme)) {
        $numaratoare ++;
        //echo " ".$informatie['nume_ro']." , ";
        array_push($cart, $informatie['obiect']);
    }
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO membri_shop_iteme set iteme_arme = ".$informatie["obiect"]." where id_jucator = ".$informatie_player['id']." "); // Here is the problem.

}
```

Where's the problem? I tried adding `implode(', ', $cart);` but still i can't add them into database.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your insert syntax is incorrect `INSERT INTO tble_name (column1,column2) VALUES(1,2);`. You are mixing an insert/update query.

Comment: Can you explain it more? Because you're not updating but inserting.

Comment: This code is a cron job, it will make a player to see only specific items every 4 hours according to his level. I want for every number stored in that array to use a comma implode(', ', $cart) and the update the values in the mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be its string problem $informatie["obiect"] to $informatie['obiect']

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO membri_shop_iteme set iteme_arme = ".$informatie['obiect']." where id_jucator = ".$informatie_player['id']." "); // Here is the problem.
```

to

```
  $newObject=join(",",$cart);
  mysql_query("UPDATE membri_shop_iteme SET iteme_arme = '".$newObject."' where id_jucator = ".$informatie_player['id']." "); // Here is the problem.
```

Comment: why are you using set you are inserting a value or update a value?

Comment: im updating a value . The original number in that varchar is 0. I want to insert something like : 1 ,2 ,3 , 4 etc for each player. This will be like a cron job at every 4 hours

Comment: can you try now? Edited.

Comment: can echo the query. echo "UPDATE membri_shop_iteme SET iteme_arme = ".$newObject." where id_jucator = ".$informatie_player['id']." ";

Comment: SET iteme_arme = '".$newObject."'

Comment: the db is connected if i use the codes      echo $informatie_player['id'];
echo " ".implode("','", $cart)."<br><br><br>";       The values will be 1 683','1146','1043','773','942','1197','40','947','751','919','858','1177 etc etc...

Comment: i deleted the row, and from varchar i made it text and now the code is working propriely. If i switch it back to varchar , the code fails. I could use the text and stay with this . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use `$informatie["obiect"]` in your query, but you have to use `$cart`.

```
while($informatie = mysql_fetch_array($shop_arme)) {
    $numaratoare ++;
    array_push($cart, $informatie['obiect']);
}

mysql_query("UPDATE membri_shop_iteme
             SET iteme_arme = '".implode("','", $cart)."'
             WHERE id_jucator = '".$informatie_player['id']."'");
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($cart)` before query to see if values are ok.

Comment: the database is ok the db is connected if i use the codes echo $informatie_player['id']; echo " ".implode("','", $cart)."<br><br><br>"; The values will be 1 683','1146','1043','773','942','1197','40','947','751','919','858','1177 etc etc...

Comment: i deleted the row, and from varchar i made it text and now the code is working propriely. If i switch it back to varchar , the code fails. I could use the text and stay with this . Thanks for your time